# How to set grid content with XAML data from socket

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I don't know what data it will be ... 
I get XAML from socket(example) :

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="180.036*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="81.964*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Margin="0,5.282,0,0" Name="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Width="109.633" Click="button1_Click">Button</Button>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,13.336,0,0" Name="textBox1" Width="123.358" Height="68.628" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

</Grid>
```

how to switch currect grid content to content that i get during the run ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XamlReader to parse the xaml you receive:

```
UIElement root = XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as UIElement;
myGrid.Children.Clear();
if(root != null)
    myGrid.Children.Add(root);
```

However, the xaml has to fulfill some conditions. All namespaces have to be included in the XAML's root node. For example:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         ....
```

Furthermore, there must be no references in the XAML that can not be solved. E.g. in the XAML you provided, there is a reference to a Click event handler that cannot be resolved. You could add the click handler after parsing the code.